# Basic control statements for Turing equivalence?

Tags: computability, programming-languages

Apologies ahead of time, I don't fully understand what I'm asking...

But, is it possible to program using only 'while loops' and still be [Turing equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)?

Or more generally, can I do everything with 'while loops' that I could with 'if statements' and 'for loops'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for(X; Y; Z) { Body; }` is just syntax sugar for `{X; while (Y) { Body; Z; }}`.

`if` can be simulated easily: rewrite `if (X) { Body; }` as `while (X) { Body; break; }`.

Comment: So can I achieve Turing equivalency using only the 'while loop'?